# Count number of games of a teams last 10 days

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to create a field that count the number of games played by a team in the past 10 days.

My dataset is like this :

```
date              Home     Visitors    Result
2020-01-01        Paris     Lisbon       1
2020-01-03        Madrid    London       1
2020-01-13        Lisbon    Madrid       1
2020-01-14        London    Paris        1
```

I want to create `df['home_last_games']` containing the number of games played by the home team past 10 days. And same for `df['visitor_last_games']` containing the number of games played by the visitor team past 10 days.

Each field should sum the past few games either the team played home or away.

Expected result here is :

```
date              Home    Visitors    Result    Home_last_games    Visitors_last_games
2020-01-01        Paris     Lisbon       1             1                       1
2020-01-03        Madrid    London       1             1                       1
2020-01-13        Lisbon    Madrid       1             1                       2
2020-01-14        London    Paris        1             1                       1
```

For now here is my code :

```
teams = df['home'].unique()

for team in teams:
    day = df['date'] - timedelta(days=10)
    df['home_last_games'] = df.loc[(df['home'] == team) & (df['date'] >= day), 'home'].count()
    df['visitor_last_games'] = df.loc[(df['visitor'] == team) & (df['date'] >= day), 'visitor'].count()
```

But this not working.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Does this counts the current game as well? For example, `Home_last_games` of `Paris` is `1` in `2020-01-01`.

Comment: Yes, i tried to implement this with the >= comparision on the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant 11 days and not 10.

Make sure your `'date'` column are dates

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

#### `stack`, `get_dummies`, and `lookup`

```
d = df.set_index('date')[['Home', 'Visitors']].stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
d = pd.get_dummies(d).sum(level=0).rolling('11D').sum()

df.assign(
    HLG=d.lookup(df.date, df.Home),
    VLG=d.lookup(df.date, df.Visitors)
)

        date    Home Visitors  Result  HLG  VLG
0 2020-01-01   Paris   Lisbon       1  1.0  1.0
1 2020-01-03  Madrid   London       1  1.0  1.0
2 2020-01-13  Lisbon   Madrid       1  1.0  2.0
3 2020-01-14  London    Paris       1  1.0  1.0
```

---

#### Some Details

`d` becomes my look up table

```
d

            Lisbon  London  Madrid  Paris
date                                     
2020-01-01     1.0     0.0     0.0    1.0
2020-01-03     1.0     1.0     1.0    1.0
2020-01-13     1.0     1.0     2.0    0.0
2020-01-14     1.0     1.0     1.0    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most effective solution, but is simple enough:

```
# make sure your date column is datetime and set it as index:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)


def get_stats(df, col, window='10D'):
    tmp_df = pd.get_dummies(df[col]).rolling(window).sum()
    return tmp_df.lookup(df.index, df[col])

# apply the function:
df['Home_last_games'] = get_stats(df, 'Home')
df['Visit_last_games'] = get_stats(df, 'Visitors')
```

Output:

```
              Home Visitors  Result  Home_last_games  Visit_last_games
date                                                                  
2020-01-01   Paris   Lisbon       1              1.0               1.0
2020-01-03  Madrid   London       1              1.0               1.0
2020-01-13  Lisbon   Madrid       1              1.0               1.0
2020-01-14  London    Paris       1              1.0               1.0
```

Comment: If you ran this for 11 days, does this count Madrid twice on the 2020-01-13?  I believe that is what OP wanted.  Though that would required 11 days and not 10.

Comment: @piRSquared I'm separating `Home` and `Visitors` so it wouldn't count `Madrid` twice. But your are correct, depending what OP wants, s/he may need to change window to `11D`.